# How to install the GCC 64 bit toolchain on a Synology DS118?

Tags: 64-bit, nas

I would like to install GCC for 64 bit on my Synology NAS DS118 (ARMv8 64 bit architecture), I've already tried using ipkg, but I noticed that it installs all packages in 32 bit.

I've tried to use Debian chroot (using last [Debian bootstrap](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/debootstrap/) following [this instruction](http://blog.fx.lv/2018/10/install-a-debian-chroot-on-your-synology-disk-station/)), but when I launch the installation script it returns the following error:

```
I: Chosen extractor for .deb packages: dpkg-deb
I: Extracting libacl1...
E: Tried to extract package, but file already exists. Exit...
```

How I can solve it? Are there any other options? Could I use other chroot (Arch Linux?)?

Comment: What you are trying to do makes no sense.  An embedded device should not be also used as a development system.  Use a desktop or laptop, and use a cross compiler.

Comment: I want to use my NAS as a little CI server, so it has to compile my code and run automatic tests nightly.

Comment: Nope it is a 64 bit processor: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-A53. `uname -m` returns `aarch64`

Comment: @sawdust makes complete sense. An embedded devise is also a computing unit, so it can be used for any computation or similar work. Whether NAS or iPhone is meant for such use or not is a different question. These are just ARM CPUs at the end of the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an updated version of software repository for Synology ([Entware](https://github.com/Entware/Entware)) which provides software compiled for 64 bit architecture and it has a quite updated GCC toolchain package.